# Reuse variable in macro with modification

Tags: c, macos

I'm trying to make a linked list for error handling in C. Functions would return the head element of the error list, or NULL.

I need macros to add file name, line numbers, ...

```cpp
#define MAKE_ERR(MSG) \
  _err_malloc(__FILE__, __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, MSG, NULL)

#define PUSH_ERR(NEXT, MSG) \
  _err_malloc(__FILE__, __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, MSG, NEXT)
```

and I would like to make it easy to add the current frame as messages go up the stack:

```cpp
#define FORWARD_ERR(NEXT) \
  (NEXT ? PUSH_ERR(NEXT, NULL) : NULL)


err_t* foo();

err_t* bar() {
  return FORWARD_ERR(foo());
}
```

The problem is that `FORWARD_ERR` uses `NEXT` twice.

I would like to use `FORWARD_ERR` as an expression. I can easily make it a block:

```cpp
#define FORWARD_ERR(NEXT) \
  { err_t* N = (NEXT); return (N ? PUSH_ERR(N, NULL) : NULL) }
```

but I don't think that's a good solution.

I was trying to get it working with the Elvis operator `a ?: b`, but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clang and GCC both support [statement expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html), which would let you do something like this:

```
#define FORWARD_ERR(NEXT) \
  ({ err_t* N = (NEXT); N ? PUSH_ERR(N, NULL) : NULL; })
```

Which lets you use it as an expression the way you want to but doesn't force you to embed the `return` statement inside your macro.

Comment: I thought this was just a GCC extension, but looks like clang has had it since at least 5.0